# How to give `` `` to mutliple lines in MD at once?

Tags: datatable, markdown, inline-code, obsidian

In Obsidian with the Markdown langauge I can put a word display as inline code by adding `` to the word.
Like test > `test`

But how can I do it at once for multiple lines in a table? For example for the following table I want to choose all the lines in Column A and and them `` at once.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| test1 | Cell 2 |
| test2 | Cell 4 |

I tried choosing them all at once and pressing `` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do all cells/columns/rows at once. You must wrap the contents of each individual cell separately. As a reminder, Markdown parsing does not happen on the content of code spans. Therefore, if you wrapped an entire line in a single code span, the column dividers would not bee seen or processed by Markdown.

```markdown
| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| `test1` | Cell 2 |
| `test2` | Cell 4 |
```

The above is rendered as follows:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| `test1` | Cell 2 |
| `test2` | Cell 4 |